# Alternative approach to subclasses with stricter input criteria

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I have an Entity class and a deriving Item class that holds some additional stuff. I am working on creating something with which I can patch such objects (ie apply a diff to them). What I currently have is an EntityPatcher class that transforms an Entity object into an associative array and then feeds this into a generic patching utility (using composition). This works great for Entity objects, but for Item objects some additional fields need to be held into account. What I started doing is creating a deriving ItemPatcher class that holds some additional stuff. This class would only be able to work with Items though, thus narrowing what the patch method accepts. Which I guess is bad, since it violates liskov substitution. I'm not sure what would be a better approach though, and am thus looking for suggestions or pointers to alternate solutions.

EntityPatcher: http://pastebin.com/CYa3ehH4

ItemPatcher: http://pastebin.com/3BReBZGH

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you would want to apply the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern